# Discord.js checking if user has the fiirst role or the second role isn't working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot check if a command has "employeeOnly" true by using `if(command.employeeOnly) //blah blah` but issue here is the roles check its supposed to check if they have the first role or the second role

```js
if (command.employeeOnly && !message.member.roles.cache.find(c => c.id === '745410836901789749') || message.member.roles.cache.find(c => c.id === '812698943288246283')) {
        return message.reply("You need taco stand employee or Bot Employee role to use that command")
    }
```

with the current code it only works if they only have the role the first role with ID (745410836901789749) but if they have the second role with the ID (812698943288246283) the return message gets send to them so I tried to put `!` on both of the `!message.member.roles.cache.find` but it didn't work either just keeps returning the messages even if they have any of the roles it also returns the messages for commands that aren't employeeOnly which is really annoying the same happens if they have both of the roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do, `...cache.find(c => c.id === '745410836901789749' || c.id==='812698943288246283');`. Inside the if statement, you are using two types of conditional operator. So for your case, it wont work. So use the `OR` operator inside the find() method.